# Dynamically updating Selectize fields using Javascript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectize.js

I have a form that contains a number of fields including some selects that are using the Selectize jquery plugin. Part of what the form does involves taking the input from a modal window, which is then added dynamically to the relevant 'selectized' select field.

I am currently doing this as follows:

```
//Initialise Selectize on the required fields
var $select = $('.selectize').selectize(...do some stuff in here...);

//Fetch the selectize instances
var select0 = $select[0].selectize;
var select1 = $select[1].selectize;
...etc, one for each select...

//This is where I get the text entered in the modal and update 
//the relevant select field.
function processText(){  

  //Get the name of the field we need to update  
  var thisFormElement = $('#sourceFormElementName').val();
  //Get the text to update the above field with
  var thisText = $('#inputQuickTextOriginalText').val();

  //Figure out which select field to update. Messy.
  if(thisFormElement == "select0"){
    //'select#' is the reference back to the selectize instances we declared earlier
    select0.addOption({value:thisText, text:thisText});
    select0.addItem(thisText);          
  }     
  else if(thisFormElement == "select1"){
    select1.addOption({value:thisText, text:thisText});
    select1.addItem(thisText);          
  }
  ...more statements...
}
```

Presumably one way to clean this up would be to reference the selectize instance using the thisFormElement value (or similar). Then there would be no need to the if statement and new fields can be added without altering this part of the code. E.g. something like:

```
//Assume thisFormElement = select0, for example
var thisFormElement = $('#sourceFormElementName').val();

thisFormElement.addOption({value:thisText, text:thisText});
thisFormElement.addItem(thisText);
```

I understand that the above won't work, but is there some way to achieve something similar (or a completely different way entirely)?

Comment: It seems like I can do something like eval(thisFormElement).addItem(thisText);   I'm not sure if this is advisable, however?

Comment: Is there a reason you are having the users add options from a separate modal rather than just using the native selectize functionality where they can do it directly in the input (see the "Tagging" demo at the following link if you don't know what I mean https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/)?

Comment: They're modifying existing options rather than adding completely new ones. I know Selectize can do this natively but I need to make sure the entries are (1) updated and not left with placeholders in place; and (2) in a specific format.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an approach to enabling users to input an option in one field and add that option to a corresponding selectize field. For those just looking for basic functionality enabling users to add new options to a selectize field, check out the [Tagging demo from the selectize documentation](https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/).

```js
const params = {
  options: [],
  placeholder: 'Select...',
  valueField: 'value',
  labelField: 'text',
  searchField: ['text'],
  create: false
};

// init selectize inputs and add to 'selects' array
const selects = [];
selects.push($('#select1').selectize(params));
selects.push($('#select2').selectize(params));
$('#add button').click(() => {
  $('#add input').each((index, elem) => {
    if (elem.value) {
      const id = $(elem).data('select-id');
      for (const select of selects) {
        // find corresponding selectize field and add option
        if (id === select[0].id) {
          const value = Object.keys(select[0].selectize.options).length + 1;
          const text = elem.value;
          select[0].selectize.addOption({value: value, text: text});
          select[0].selectize.addItem(value);
          break;
        }
      }
      
      elem.value = '';
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Selectize</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.6/css/selectize.default.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.6/js/standalone/selectize.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="add">
      <div>
        <input name="add1" type="text" value="" placeholder="Add option to 1st select..." data-select-id="select1" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <input name="add2" type="text" value="" placeholder="Add option to 2nd select..." data-select-id="select2" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <button>Add</button>
      </div>
    </div> 
    <br>
    <form id="select" action="" method="POST">
      <input class="myselect" id="select1" name="select1" type="text" />
      <input class="myselect" id="select2" name="select2" type="text" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```